# C language basics 1

Tags: c

What is the difference between a++ and a=a+1 in C if a is a variable.
Tell me the difference between the following assignments;

```
x=a+1;
x=a++;
```

I am not able to find a convincing explanation on Google.Please explain the difference clearly and step by step.

Comment: What about trying it?

Comment: The `++` in your example is called the post-increment operator. That should help you with googling.

Answer (score 2):

`a = a+1;` calculates the result of `a+1` and assigns it to `a`.
`a++;` increments `a` by `1`, but evaluates to the previous value of `a`.
`++a;` increments `a` by `1`, and evaluates to the new value of `a`.
`a += 1` is identical to `++a;`.

So for example:
`x = a++;` → `a` will be incremented by `1`, and the previous value of `a` will be assigned to `x`.
`x = ++a;` → `a` will be incremented by `1`, and the new value of `a` will be assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

`x=a+1` just sets the value of `x`.
`x=a++` first sets `x` to the value of `a`, and then increments `a`. `a++` is an operation in itself, and you could call it as a single statement to increment `a`, without assigning it to `x` whatsoever.

FYI, there is also `++a`, which could be used like this:

`x=++a`. In this case, `a` is incremented first, and then the incremented value is assigned to `x`. In either case, the `++` operator modifies `a`, which is not the case for `a+1`.

Answer (score 1):

From the C11 Standard (draft):

> **6.5.2.4 Postfix increment [...] operator[...]**
>
> [...]
>
> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
>   value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
>   added to it).

So

```
int a = 0;
int x = a++;
```

results in `a` being `1` and `x` being `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`x = a++` returns the value of `a` to the variable `x` first and later it is incremented.

`x = a+1` Here `a+1` is evaluated and the result is stored in `x`

Answer (score 0):

3 differences

1. Return value and side effect

   ```
   // a is incremented, but its former value is assigned to x 
   x=a++;  // 
   // a is unchanged.  The sum of `a+1`is assigned to x 
   x=a+1;
   ```
2. [Operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).  post-fix `++` (aka Suffix increment) is higher precedence than simple addition.
3. `++` only works with integer and non-`void*` pointer types.  `+1` works with all scalar type including `double`.

   ```
   int a;
   x=a++; // valid
   x=a+1; // valid

   double a;
   x=a++; // invalid
   x=a+1; // valid
   ```